# different shades of color when images used in different divs?

Tags: image

On my website is a centered cta image and a repeated sliced image to fill the fluid left and right columns which are presenting as different shades, however the background for the sides is a slice from photoshop of the centered image. Is this some aspect of css that I was unaware of? The images are both backgrounds, one container inside another as such:

```
    <div class="cta_main">
    <div class="cta"></div>
    </div>
```

with the styles like this:

```
    .cta {
        width:1000px;
        height:350px;
        margin:0 auto;
        background-image:url(../images/images/cta_reg_07.png);
        background-repeat:no-repeat;
        z-index:100;
       }    
    .cta_main {
        width:100%;
        height:350px;
        margin:0 auto;
        background-image:url(../images/images/cta_reg_20.png);
        background-repeat:repeat-x;
        z-index:1;
       }
```

In photoshop the images are naturally the same color (since one is a slice of the other), even in dreamweaver it appears the way it should, only in firefox and chrome (i didnt test any other browsers) does the cta image look a few shades lighter. Thanks.

Comment: You should really link to an example website, or at least include a screenshot. Most likely, you didn't export the images to the same color space in PhotoShop.

Comment: both images are standard png 24s, ill try figuring out a screen shot, thanks!

Comment: A screenshot can only tell us if you're color-blind ;) An actual website would be way better, so that we can see and experiment for ourselves.